# use a loop to write columns of a csv file in writerow{ }

Tags: python-3.x, csv

11 columns in a csv file, header of 1st column is 'Week', then the rest headers are 'Person1', 'Person2' ... 'Person10'. 
Use csv's writerow to write multiple rows to the csv files in a for loop. But how to do a loop to write each column? for example:

```
writer.writerow({'Week': xxx,
                 for i in range (1, 11):
                     'Person{}'.format(i): some value,
                     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `writerow` does not need you to pass in a dictionary with header names in each call. You can just pass a list/iterable of the field values as strings.

Anyway, what you're attempting can be achieved if you replace the `for` loop above with a "list comprehension", the Pythonic way.

```
fieldnames = ['Week'] + ['Person{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,11)]
writer.writerow(dict(fieldnames, [xxx] + [value for i in range(1,11)]))
```

You need to fill in the logic to get `value` in each iteration of the second `for` loop.

Comment: used dict(zip(fieldnames,[values])), and all good now. Thanks.